# Spray client - treat response with unexpected content-type as application/json?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, spray, spray-json, spray-client

When I try to GET amazon identity data like that

```
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[IdentityData] = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[IdentityData]
pipeline(Get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document"))
```

with appropriate case class and formatter, I receive the following exception

UnsupportedContentType(Expected 'application/json')

because amazon mark their response as *text/plain* content type. They also don't care about the *Accept* header param. Is there an easy way to tell spray-json to ignore this on unmarshalling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extract some `IdentityData` (which is a case class with a defined `jsonFormat`) from amazon response, which is a valid json, but with `text/plain` context type you can simply extract text data, parse it a json and convert into your data, e.g:

```
entity.asString.parseJson.convertTo(identityDataJsonFormat)
```

Comment: Didn't think to do it that straightforward. Thanks for the reminder to check simple options :-)

Comment: After hours of frustration, this really helped. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

After digging in spray mail list I wrote a function that works

```
def mapTextPlainToApplicationJson: HttpResponse => HttpResponse = {
  case r@ HttpResponse(_, entity, _, _) =>
    r.withEntity(entity.flatMap(amazonEntity => HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/json`), amazonEntity.data)))
  case x => x
}
```

and the used it in the pipeline

```
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[IdentityData] = sendReceive ~> mapTextPlainToApplicationJson ~> unmarshal[IdentityData]
pipeline(Get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document"))
```

The cool thing is here you can intercept & alter any *HttpResponse* as long as your intercepting function has the appropriate signature.

Comment: There is no need to write your function, there is `mapHttpResponseEntity` directive

Comment: And also there is no need in matching on HttpResponse entity and apply `withEntity`, cause it will check your entity arg and apply it if it is different (including empty entity case), so you can simply do `_.withEntity(..)`

Comment: This solution is good, but would be improved by making sure that the `HttpCharset` from the original response's `ContentType` is preserved. Set the new content-type value to `ContentType(MediaTypes.\`applicaiton/json\`, amazonEntity.contentType.charset)`

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a simpler/cleaner version of @yevgeniy-mordovkin's solution.

```
def setContentType(mediaType: MediaType)(r: HttpResponse): HttpResponse = {
  r.withEntity(HttpEntity(ContentType(mediaType), r.entity.data))
}
```

Usage:

```
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[IdentityData] = (
       sendReceive
    ~> setContentType(MediaTypes.`application/json`)
    ~> unmarshal[IdentityData]
)
pipeline(Get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document"))
```

Comment: This is going to work only if the producer cares about what you are asking for. In my case it doesn't.

Comment: I think you misread my post. I do the same thing as you (set the content type _after_ receiving the response), only the code is a bit cleaner. Minor improvement, nothing radical.